# Como usar uma fetch_array contida em outra página PHP?

Tags: php

Exemplo: O SELEC Tem três nomes, quero imprimir esses 3 nomes em outra pagina.

### pagina1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php 
$sql = $db->query("SELECT nome FROM banco_de_dados");//SELECT TEM 3 nomes (vitor,matheus,carol)
?>

<?php
    while($dados = $sql->fetch_array()){
    $nome = $dados['nome'];

    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
    };

?>
```

---

### pagina2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];
echo $nome;
?>
```

---

imprimir na pagina:

```
vitor
matheus
carol
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pagina1.php**

```
while($dados = $sql->fetch_array()){
//concatena os nomes separando-os por virgula
$nomes .= $dados['nome'].",";
};

//retira a ultima virgula
$nomes=substr($nomes, 0, -1);
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nomes; / vitor,matheus,carol
```

**pagina2.php**

Se for só imprimir cada nome em uma linha, faz replace de virgula por quebra de linha

```
session_start();
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];

echo str_replace(',','<br>',$nome);
```

ou

```
session_start();

$nomes = explode(',',$_SESSION['nome']);

echo $nomes[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $nomes[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $nomes[2];
```

Comment: Poxa cara me ajudou muito. Muito mesmo.
Vlw

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está meia confusa, mas acho que entendi. No caso só está imprimindo um nome por que  o nome está sendo sobrescrito na **$_SESSION** (Já tive esse problema no meu TCC). O que pode ser feito para resolver esse problema é em vez de usar **$_SESSION** você pode chamar a página direto, assim:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");

$sql = $db->query("SELECT nome FROM banco_de_dados");//SELECT TEM 3 nomes (vitor,matheus,carol)

while($dados = $sql->fetch_array()){
echo $dados['nome'];
}
```

Já na página onde será mostrado:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'pagina1.php';
```

Assim ele executará a página1 na página2, mostrando os dados dentro da página2.

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
$num = 0;
while($dados = $sql->fetch_array()){
$nome = $dados['nome'];
$_SESSION['nome_id'.$num] = $nome;
$num++;
}
```

já na página 2 você põe a sequência:

```
echo $_SESSION["nome_id1"];
echo $_SESSION["nome_id2"];
echo $_SESSION["nome_id3"];
```

Ou faz como o membro da primeira resposta.

Comment: Amigo Léo, Sua informação me ajudou 50%.
Vou tentar reformular minha pergunta para ver se ha  possibilidade de você me ajudar.

Já agradeço pelo sua ajuda.